# QObject connect fails in Qt

Tags: qt, c++11

everyone!

I am having a problem using QObject::connect with some custom classes I've created. First of all, I have created 2 classes that inherit from **QObject**, they are called: Valve and PushButton. They are instantiated inside controllers called PanelController and SynopticController, which are also QObjects. And these controllers are instantiated inside another class called MasterController, also a QObject. I find this information useful since I think it is a problem of referencing the classes or the way I might be instantiating my classes inside these controllers. I strongly think this, because in my main method, when I do the following snippet of code, the connection works:

```
...
avionics::synoptic::Valve valveTest(nullptr, avionics::synoptic::ValveName::ABV);
avionics::panel::PushButton pushButtonTest(nullptr, avionics::panel::PanelNames::RECIRC);

QObject::connect(&pushButtonTest, &avionics::panel::PushButton::onStateColorChanged, &valveTest, &avionics::synoptic::Valve::updateState);
...
```

Basically, the controller classes are:

```
// MasterController
class MasterController : public QObject {
...

private:
        panel::PanelController* panelController{nullptr};
        synoptic::SynopticController* synopticController{nullptr};
}

// Panel Controller
class PanelController : public QObject {
...

explicit PanelController(QObject *parent = nulptr){
        this->pushButtons.append(new avionics::panel::PushButton(_panelController, avionics::panel::PanelNames::RECIRC));
}

private:
        QList<avionics::panel::PushButton*> pushButtons{};
}

// SynopticController
class SynopticController : public QObject {

private: 
        QList<avionics::synoptic::Valve*> iceValves{};

explicit SynopticController(QObject *parent = nullptr) {
        antiIcePneumaticLines.append(new avionics::synoptic::PneumaticLine(_synopticController, avionics::synoptic::PneumaticLineName::APU_2_ABV));
}

}
```

My problem is that when I do the same call for the QObject::connect either from my MasterController constructor or my main method, the signal doesn't call the slot function. I want to connect pushButtons to valves, and to do this I am using getters from my controllers. The call to QObject::connect that doesn't work is:

```
QObject::connect(panelController->getpushButtons().at(1), &avionics::panel::PushButton::onStateColorChanged, synopticController->getValves().at(1), &avionics::synoptic::Valve::updateState);


// Example of getter
QList<avionics::panel::PushButton*> PanelController::getPushButtons(){
    return pushButtons;
}
```

I've put some prints inside the method that emits the signal and tried debugging it, but the signal is emitted and the slot isn't called. The classes return from the getters are not undefined or null, I've checked it. Let me know if something wasn't clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any worker threads in your app? The only cases which come to mind when the slots are really connected and yet not called are: 1) the signal receiver is deleted before the slot is called; 2) the receiver lives in another thread without QEventLoop.

Comment: I am working on a single thread, @absolute.madness. I've also tried Q_ASSERT(response), using the returned value from QObject::connect() and I receive 1 (true)

Comment: I see. Would be nice to have it reproduced, because honestly, it's hard for me to tell from the details you've provided. It's also quite strange to call a signal `onStateColorChanged`, usually `on`- prefix is used for slots, but this has nothing to do with not calling a slot. Btw, signal is simply a function you can call it like `emit synopticController->getValves().at(1)` to test if it leads to the slot invocation after corresponding connect. Also, you showed you connect the button with index 1. This was an example, right? It should be connected in a loop in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll change the signal's name to match the convention, it really sounds weird to put the **on** prefix. The connection with index 1 was just an example to test if it was working. Ideally, I would connect all the pushButtons with valves in loop like you said. I am not sure if I understand what you meant by calling the signal, but the method that emits the signal is the one below:
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you meant by calling the signal, but the method that emits the signal is the one below:
`
void PushButton::setState(avionics::synoptic::PneumaticState::Status state){
    if(this->state != state){
        this->state = state;
        this->stateColor = mapStateToColor[state];
        emit onStateColorChanged(state);
    }
}
`
I've also put some prints to see if the signal was being emitted and it does, but the slot isn't called. I'll work on reproducing the problem in a simplified project in the mean time. Thanks, @absolute.madness

Comment: By calling the signal I meant that you can call it on demand from the code as a normal method (for debugging purposes) - since you mentioned that in one scenario the slot is called while in another is not.

Comment: Got it, @absolute.madness. I actually have a QML application that calls a method every time I click in an element. Visually in the application as well as in the output, I can see that the slot function isn't called when I do the connection from elements that are inside the QLists in the controllers. Very strange indeed. Because if I instantiate both elements and connect them, it works.

Comment: Good news, @absolute.madness. I've found the problem in my code by trying to reproduce the problem. The problem seems to be the way I had my properties is_failed and is_active set up regarding how to NOTIFY changes. Now it works, thanks a lot for the help. I really appreciate it! The example code, if anyone wants to see it, is in the following [link](https://github.com/Sereno29/Qt-Example)